# Symfony2 - Doctrine query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have problem with Doctrine query in my Symfony2 project.
That my code:

```
public function getLender($lender) {
    $lender = str_replace("_", " ", $lender);
    $this->qb->select('ld, ld.entry, ll.name, ll.logo')
        ->from('PageMainBundle:LoanDescription', 'ld')
        ->leftJoin(
           'PageMainBundle:loanLender',
           'll',
           \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
           'ld.lender = ll.lenderId'
           )    
        ->where('ll.name=?1')   
        ->setParameter(1, $lender);     
    return $this->qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

When in select section i choose columns it works very well - returns values of columns. unforunelly when I try something like that:

```
$this->qb->select('ld')
```

I don't get pure values but sometkhing strange. 
How can I get values of all db columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "strange" thing is most probably an `LoanDescription` collection of object (entity) instances. So to get value of `entry` field you need to call `$entity->getEntry()` on this entity object (assuming that you have such method defined in your entity)

**OR**

You can use `getArrayResult` instead of `getResult` and you should get array with valies